# jQuery expandable menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="firstDiv">
    <div id="secondDiv">
        <ul id="accordionMenu">
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">suboption 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to make it expandable?

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Collapse everything but the first menu:
    $("#accordionMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);
    // Expand or collapse:
    $("#accordionMenu > li > a").click(function() {
        $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Comment: what isn't working? Are you seeing errors? Strange behavior? Please describe it.

Comment: @Random see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: @Mathletics: My menu is not expanding, don't know why. No JavaScript errors

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fGEpx/  works fine for me, though I'd use `.hide();` instead of `.slideUp(1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Yoshi: Thank you. I'll add the answer here, hope will help others

**HTML**

```
<div id="firstDiv">
    <div id="secondDiv">
        <ul id="accordionMenu">
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">suboption 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">suboption 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
// Collapse everything but the first menu:
$("#accordionMenu > li > a").not(":first").find("+ ul").slideUp(1);

// Expand or collapse:
$("#accordionMenu > li > a").click(function() {
    $(this).find("+ ul").slideToggle("fast");
});​
```

Don't forget to include jQuery library :)

Comment: Mind stating which jQuery library you are referring to here?

Comment: @fraxture: Meaning which version? jQuery  >= 1.9.x